# Disable moving fullscreen windows when clicking on a Dock app

Tags: macos, dock, fullscreen

In order to organize my workspace I arrange my fullscreen apps in appropriate order, so I know what app is on the left and on the right from my current position.

However when I start an app by clicking on a dock icon and move to the desktop, my current fullscreen window places to the first position automatically, right next after the desktop.

How can I prevent macOS from this automatic change order of windows? It's very annoying to replace them manually again and again.

Answer (score 5):

System Preferences → Mission Control and uncheck ‘Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use’.

[image]